# How to find the Convex Hull

Tags: computational-geometry

How can I plot the convex hull for some points in 3D

For example:
I want the convex hull for (4,0,0), (2,0,4), (0,1,6), (0,0,10), (0,4,0)

If there are some ways to find it I need to know it.

Thank you

Comment: did you do some search before asking?

Comment: Yes I did but I did not get what I want :)
Thank you for your help

Comment: -1 because I cannot find a single way to search for this that does not immediately give you the answer.  Did you google for "mathematica convex hull"?  Did you open the documentation center and type in "convex hull"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ConvexHullMesh[
   {{4, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 6}, {0, 0, 10}, {0, 4, 0}}
              ]
```

[image]

Your Convex Hull comprises precisely the points you provided.

```
data = {{4, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 6}, {0, 0, 10}, {0, 4, 0}};
Show[
 ConvexHullMesh[data,
  ViewPoint -> {.5, -2, -1}],
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.06], Point[data]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there better way to see inside the convex hull

Comment: Run the code and rotate the figure by yourself.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to see inside, but try this:  `Show[ConvexHullMesh[data, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> Opacity[0.5, Orange]}], 
 Graphics3D[Point[data]]]`

Comment: Thanks I really got what I want :)

Comment: Is there a way to see xyz coordinates?

Comment: @Ateq:  Just add:  `Axes-> True, Boxed ->True`.